# Use Heroku with Node.js to make only a CRUD application?

Tags: android, node.js, postgresql, heroku, crud

I'm a incredibly newbie in Programmming, it's been 6 months of a course and me and a team want to make some kind of social network job searching app with Android Studio.

I wanted to know how possible is to make a relatively simple CRUD application with Heroku+Node.js probably using Postgresql or if adding Heroku is just making it more complicated.

I would like just to have several routes in my Node.js to connect from the app to the server's database. Sorry if I haven't been so clear, it's my first time posting here and I couldn't find a post that answered my question. Thank you!

Comment: Heroku is only an hosting plateform, it doesn't make your app more or less complicated. You could use [express](http://expressjs.com) to create your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Heroku for deploying your Node.js app
You can use express.js framework for writing your CRUD code in node.js

You can take help of 
https://github.com/scotch-io/node-mongoose-heroku